# Portainer keeps getting back with New Portainer installation

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi4, portainer

I am trying to run Portainer on Raspberry Pi 4.
After creating the admin user I can't get pass the time out warning.

> our Portainer instance timed out for security purposes. To re-enable your Portainer instance, you will need to restart Portainer.

Tried:

- stopping and starting Portainer

```
 sudo docker restart portainer
```

- recreating the container
- using another port

Anyone an idea of whats wrong here?
Thanks for yr effort in advance JB